# How to display the date using API foursquare -PHP

Tags: php, foursquare

I am creating an app that can view the check'ins, I achieved show some data, but I can not display the date, I've read the API documntacion, and found the following:

```
    id: "5107ed69704379518de3cb5f"
    createdAt: 1359474025
    type: "checkin"
    timeZoneOffset: -420
    user: {
        id: "46466115"
        firstName: "Abraham"
        lastName: "Gonzalez"
        gender: "male"
        relationship: "self"
        photo: {
            prefix: "https://irs3.4sqi.net/img/user/"
            suffix: "/JB543SD4TURRQR2A.jpg"
        }
```

I try to implement it, but It shows  a string of numbers, and I want to know how to interpret these numbers, I have done some research and found that the numbers are seconds(http://www.epochconverter.com/), but I do not know how to interpret them: (

It is my php code:

```
$check_ins =json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?oauth_token={$_SESSION['access_token']}"));
foreach($check_ins->response->checkins->items as $check_in):
        echo"

            <b>Lugar</b>: ".$check_in->venue->name."
            <br><b>Pais</b>: ".$check_in->venue->location->country."
            <br><b>Ciudad</b>: ".$check_in->venue->location->city."
            <br><b>Estado</b>: ".$check_in->venue->location->state."
            <b><br>Dirección</b>: ".$check_in->venue->location->address."
            **<b><br>Dirección</b>: ".$check_in->createdAt."**
            <br><br>";  
endforeach;
```

And so, my question is: How to show the date/or how can interpret the numbers foursquare give me?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
echo date("F j, Y H:i:s", $check_in->createdAt);
```

It's just a timestamp so a basic date function should work.
If I misunderstood, please comment and I can update.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your help, Kai Qing

Answer (score 0):

That is clearly a Unix timestamp value.  You can use the PHP `date()` function or `DateTime` object to turn this into a human readable format.

Now what is unclear is whether that timestamp includes the time zone offset value (i.e. the timestamp is localized to the time zone so you need to apply the offset to it to get UTC), or whether it is UTC value and you need to apply to offset to get the localized time of the check-in.  You will probably need to look at the documentation for that, or just do some experimenting to find out.

Answer (score 0):

That number is a timestamp. You can convert it into human readable string with the date function:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $yourNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHPs date function:, the first part is the format you want, the second is the unix timestamp:

```
echo date('d m Y h:i', 1359474025);

29 01 2013 04:40
```